# Getting coefficients of quadratic function with indicator in R

Tags: r

I have the left side formula like as follows and I expand it to the right side , which `+` means that if `b`_i is bigger than `x`, it's `b_i - x`, else it's zero. I can write the code of left side formula as below but how can I get the coefficients of quadratic right side formula in R?

\sum_{i=1}^{2}a_i(b_i - x)^2_{+}  = \sum_{i=1}^{2} a_i (b_i^2 I (b_i >= x) + x^2 I (b_i >= x) - 2 b_i x I (b_i >= x))

```
      a = c(1, 2)
      b = c(10, 30)
      x = c(5, 15, 50, 100)
      > colSums(a * pmax(outer(b, x, "-"), 0)^2)
      [1] 1275  450    0    0
```

Comment: Instead of creating your own symbolic syntax, how about using standard logicals, e.g. `b_i <- ifelse(b_i > x, bi_i -x, 0)` ?  By `b-i` do you mean `b[i]` ?

Comment: Yes, we can. By b_i I mean b[i].